# How to scroll two textboxes at the same time

Tags: vb.net

The goal here is to scroll the richtextbox2 while scrolling richtextbox1 at the same time.
I tried ...

```
Dim currentLine As integer=0
Dim index As integer=0

Private sub richtextbox1_textChanged(s as sender,e as eventArgs)handles richtextbox1.textChanged
index=richtextbox1.selectionStart
currentLine=richtextbox.GetLineFromCharIndex(index)
End sub

 Private sub richtextbox1_vscroll()  handlesrichtextbox.vscroll
Dim i=currentLine+1
Richtextbox2.select(i,1)
Richtextbox2.scrollToCaret()
End sub
```

Comment: This code is incorrect. Please post your actual code and explain how do you initialize (and update) the currentLine variable

Comment: initialized publicly as integer and value 0.CurentLine is updated inside sub richtextbox1.textchanged

Comment: What is the goal here? Scroll the second RTB when the first one is scrolled? When? When the Text of RTB1 changes? When a user moves the current insert point? When the scrollbars are repositioned? All/Some of the above?

Comment: The goal is to scroll the second rtb when the first one is scrolled.actually i need it for texteditor app rtb1 for code area rtb2 lines then when I scroll both rtbs must scroll.

Comment: Are you OK to P/Invoke for this (using SendMessage)? It's the most straightforward method, but of course it will work on Windows only. There's also UI Automation, but in this case is overly complicated for no good reason. Or just calculations. But your code may become  (including error/corner case handling) a bit too long.